# Converting Typescript Code to Javascript Code?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redis, shopify

I'm using [Shopify's Node Api](https://github.com/Shopify/shopify-node-api/blob/main/docs/usage/customsessions.md#create-a-redisstore-class) tutorial to create a Redis store. However, the code block provided is in typescript and my entire project is written in javascript (React/nextjs). I've been working for a few hours to try and convert the code to be useable, but am unable to get it to work properly in my project. Seriously struggling with this.

How would I convert the below code block from typescript to javascript?

```
/* redis-store.ts */

// Import the Session type from the library, along with the Node redis package, and `promisify` from Node
import {Session} from '@shopify/shopify-api/dist/auth/session';
import redis from 'redis';
import {promisify} from 'util';

class RedisStore {
  private client: redis.RedisClient;
  private getAsync;
  private setAsync;
  private delAsync;

  constructor() {
    // Create a new redis client
    this.client = redis.createClient();
    // Use Node's `promisify` to have redis return a promise from the client methods
    this.getAsync = promisify(this.client.get).bind(this.client);
    this.setAsync = promisify(this.client.set).bind(this.client);
    this.delAsync = promisify(this.client.del).bind(this.client);
  }

  /*
    The storeCallback takes in the Session, and sets a stringified version of it on the redis store
    This callback is used for BOTH saving new Sessions and updating existing Sessions.
    If the session can be stored, return true
    Otherwise, return false
  */
  storeCallback = async (session: Session) => {
    try {
      // Inside our try, we use the `setAsync` method to save our session.
      // This method returns a boolean (true if successful, false if not)
      return await this.setAsync(session.id, JSON.stringify(session));
    } catch (err) {
      // throw errors, and handle them gracefully in your application
      throw new Error(err);
    }
  };

  /*
    The loadCallback takes in the id, and uses the getAsync method to access the session data
     If a stored session exists, it's parsed and returned
     Otherwise, return undefined
  */
  loadCallback = async (id: string) => {
    try {
      // Inside our try, we use `getAsync` to access the method by id
      // If we receive data back, we parse and return it
      // If not, we return `undefined`
      let reply = await this.getAsync(id);
      if (reply) {
        return JSON.parse(reply);
      } else {
        return undefined;
      }
    } catch (err) {
      throw new Error(err);
    }
  };

  /*
    The deleteCallback takes in the id, and uses the redis `del` method to delete it from the store
    If the session can be deleted, return true
    Otherwise, return false
  */
  deleteCallback = async (id: string) => {
    try {
      // Inside our try, we use the `delAsync` method to delete our session.
      // This method returns a boolean (true if successful, false if not)
      return await this.delAsync(id);
    } catch (err) {
      throw new Error(err);
    }
  };
}

// Export the class
export default RedisStore;
```

Comment: The only bits of typescript in there are the `Session` interface, `string` types on methods and the `private` key words of the class. Just remove those and save the file as `.js`

Comment: Or use the TypeScript compiler, that's its job!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just save all that typescript code in a .ts file (probably redis-store.ts).
then use typescript compiler to convert to your version of javascript by just running tsc command as below

```
tsc redis-store.ts
```

for more compiler options, please visit below
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html

Answer (score 1):

You basically need to get rid of all the types (Session and string) and switch `private` to `#`, maybe something like this:

```js
/* redis-store.js */

import redis from 'redis';
import {promisify} from 'util';

class RedisStore {
  #client;
  #getAsync;
  #setAsync;
  #delAsync;

  constructor() {
    // Create a new redis client
    this.client = redis.createClient();

    this.getAsync = promisify(this.client.get).bind(this.client);
    this.setAsync = promisify(this.client.set).bind(this.client);
    this.delAsync = promisify(this.client.del).bind(this.client);
  }

  storeCallback = async (session) => {
    try {
      // Inside our try, we use the `setAsync` method to save our session.
      // This method returns a boolean (true if successful, false if not)
      return await this.setAsync(session.id, JSON.stringify(session));
    } catch (err) {
      // throw errors, and handle them gracefully in your application
      throw new Error(err);
    }
  };

  /*
    The loadCallback takes in the id, and uses the getAsync method to access the session data
     If a stored session exists, it's parsed and returned
     Otherwise, return undefined
  */
  loadCallback = async (id) => {
    try {
      // Inside our try, we use `getAsync` to access the method by id
      // If we receive data back, we parse and return it
      // If not, we return `undefined`
      let reply = await this.getAsync(id);
      if (reply) {
        return JSON.parse(reply);
      } else {
        return undefined;
      }
    } catch (err) {
      throw new Error(err);
    }
  };

  /*
    The deleteCallback takes in the id, and uses the redis `del` method to delete it from the store
    If the session can be deleted, return true
    Otherwise, return false
  */
  deleteCallback = async (id) => {
    try {
      // Inside our try, we use the `delAsync` method to delete our session.
      // This method returns a boolean (true if successful, false if not)
      return await this.delAsync(id);
    } catch (err) {
      throw new Error(err);
    }
  };
}

// Export the class
export default RedisStore;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I implemented the above code but it's throwing an error on `#client`. `Support for the experimental syntax 'classPrivateProperties' isn't currently enabled` Digging into it deeper now

Comment: I've seen this error before, i think it depends on the browser not sure, you can remove `#` and should work